# Pause after each line in javascript

Tags: javascript, debugging

I would like to have a program pause after each line is executed in javascript.  This is for a teaching tool where the user will type in there js and be able to step though it line by line.  I want to then be able to step through each line and pause after it is executed.  Something line popping up an alert() between each line, but without the dialogue.

Is this possible?

I am looking to keep it in the browser and not use DevTools or Firebug.

Comment: If you can edit the code, you could always put a `debugger` statement after each line. But it would be much easier (and more cross browser compatible) to just use the debugger to start with.

Comment: Are you talking about writing an application that acts as a debugger?  Or are you saying that you want to step through code for teaching people (in person or screen sharing)?

Comment: @GJK yes, but then it goes into the DevTools/Firebug area.  I want the user to stay in the browser and not have to deal w that.

Comment: @JimSchubert I want to step through code that the user has written in an text area and execute it line by line, within the chrome and not using devtool/firebug

Comment: I don't think that is possible unless you write your own javascript interpreter.

Comment: Is your goal to create a browser-based IDE like [Cloud9](https://c9.io/)?

Comment: What you're asking for is what a debugger does.  You should either use a debugger or get the code from one and modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: @JimSchubert sort of but this is much more focused on the debugging.  Cloud9 is really about the editing and remote execution of code.  I'm looking for something that can help people learn where the problems are in the code

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you run your code through FireBug (which is a FireFox extension).

Get [firefox here](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/)
[Get firebug here](http://getfirebug.com/downloads)